# Restrict access to my images on other website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-headers, ihttphandler

I have website made in ASP.net MVC3 and hosted images on it. But other websites are using my images links and stealing my bandwidth. Is there a way to check each request using http headers and send different response regarding website name?

Please suggest me a article or help me in this.

Thanks and regards

Comment: You need to restrict access to anonymous users to files/folders, there are configuration you need to set in your configuration file. have a look in [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx "Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent accessing those image by **not** posting their actual path on your server.
Read  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

This is how your < img > tag will look like :

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K....." id="pictureFrame"/>
```

This piece of code will do the job for the image in C#

```
private void encryptPhoto(string imagePath)
{
    pictureFrame.Src = @"data:image/gif;base64," + EncodePhoto(Server.MapPath(imagePath));
}
private string EncodePhoto(string fileName)
{
        return Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
}
```

Comment: its, nice trick. my website is a greetings website, and people send these links to social networking websites like facebook, tagged etc so I just want to restrict few websites who are sending my images urls to social networks with their back link to their own website. Thats why I don't want to give access to those websites.

Comment: If i was able to give you an answer, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but what you can do is store a list of the actual image file names in some secret text file and read them in with PHP or something similar to actually display them.  Then you can change the image names in the file system and text file so your site will look fine, but you can make the old image files point to new images that say "THIS IMAGE WAS STOLEN FROM [MYDOMAIN]"  That should curb the stealing pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

you can ignore that images using MVC routing. define route pattern as per your requirement.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("foldername/{filename}.html");
}
```